# Delete an item (row) from table but keep the unused ID number for a future insertion

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite, sql-insert, sql-delete

I have a database with an "inventory" table which contains products from a shop. Each product is identified using an **ID** number set in the "ID" column of the table.
I want to be able to delete a product from the table, but keeping the deleted product's id number for future product insertions into the database. 
As a demonstration I inserted 4 items and named all of them "test"

[image]

And just as an example I named the "deleted" product as "vacio" (empty in spanish) to show the one that i deleted.

[image]

Now, if want to add another product in the future, the id number 2 is unused and I want to add the product with that id number instead of 4 (following the given example).

The DELETE query is no good since it erases the id number as well so its a no go.
I thought about checking for the first row of the table that contains the value "vacio" and using the UPDATE query in all fields except id but this doesnt feel "classy" and is not very efficient as It should have to update values a lot of times.
Is there some nice way of doing this?

Comment: Is there any specifc reason why you want to keep re-use the deleted `id`s? This might cause integrity issues, if you have other tables referencing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not actually recommend reusing old identifiers. For one, this prevents you from using the `auto_increment` feature, which mean that you need to manually handle the column for each and every insertion: this adds complexity and is not efficient. Also, it might cause integrity issues in your database if you have other tables referencing the product id.

But if you really want to go that way: I would go for the deletion option. If there are foreign keys referencing the column, make sure that they have the `on delete cascade` option enabled so data is properly purged from dependent tables when a product is dropped.

Then, you can fill the first available gap the next time your create a new product with the following query:

```
insert into products(id, categoria, producto)
select min(id) + 1, 'my new category', 'my new product'
from products p
where not exists (select 1 from products p1 where p1.id = p.id + 1)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i'll go with not reusing old identifiers and implementing the `auto_increment` feature

Answer (score 1):

You could have a new column ESTADO where you handle if a record is active (1) or inactive (0). Then, to obtain only "undeleted" records you just have to filter by the new column. That way, you also prevent changing the product name to "vacio", which might be useful in the future.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I'll go with GMB's solution of not reusing old id numbers so I dont cause cross-table integrity issues

Answer (score -1):

Find the highest number in the auto increment field
To find the highest number, run the following SQL command:

SELECT MAX( `column` ) FROM `table` ;
Replace ‘column’ with the name of the auto incrementing column. Replace table with the name of the table.

Reset the auto increment field
The next step is to take the number that you get from the first command and auto increment from there. So add one to that number and run the following command:

ALTER TABLE `table` AUTO_INCREMENT = number;

Replacing ‘number’ with the result of the previous command plus one and replacing table with the table name.

If you deleted all the rows in the table, then you could run the alter table command and reset it to 0.

Hope this help!

[Reference](https://befused.com/mysql/reset-auto-increment/)

Comment: The question is tagged SQLite. The reference link in your answer is about MySql. Your code does not work in SQLite.